# Is it possible to abort sending an email once an ActionMailer method has been called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Let's say I've called an actionmailer method which resides in a mailer.

I do the processing to determine if there are to be any recipients of the email in this method. Sometimes there are none, but it appears that once this method is called, it is impossible to abort sending. Finishing the method without setting a recipient throws an error. Is that correct? Is there no way to abort?

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: Is it the mailers job to decide whether to send an email or not?  Surely this is the job of the calling controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the type of case where you should consider raising your own exception. You can define it in lib, and then catch it in the code that calls your mailer.

```
class AbortMailingException < Exception
end

# In your mailer ...
if !have_enough_recipients()  # Or whatever conditions / checks you want to perform.
  raise AbortMailingException.new
end

# In the code that calls your mailer ...
begin
  my_mailer_function(args)
rescue AbortMailingException => e
  # Handle error, log, ignore, whatever
end
```